# R travis error: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: r, curl, https, travis-ci

I'm trying to test an R package with travis and having troubles with an internal cmake command failing to download from https. In the R package's configure script it downloads and cmake's a metapackage from github. The download and install begin properly but it fails with the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target HDF5

[  3%] Creating directories for 'HDF5'

[  3%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'HDF5'

-- downloading...

src='https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/src/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1.tar.bz2'

dst='/tmp/minc-toolkit-v2/build/HDF5-prefix/src/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1.tar.bz2'

timeout='none'

CMake Error at HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-stamp/download-HDF5.cmake:27 (message):

error: downloading

'https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/src/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1.tar.bz2'

failed

status_code: 1

status_string: "Unsupported protocol"

log: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

  Closing connection -1
```

Prior to this issue I was having problems getting a more recent version of cmake than the 2.xx provided by the travis build machines. My .travis.yml looks like this at the moment:

```
language: r
sudo: require
cache: packages
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - george-edison55-precise-backports # cmake 3.2.3 / doxygen 1.8.3
    packages:
      - openssl
      - libssl-dev
      - libcurl4-openssl-dev
      - cmake
      - cmake-data
repos:
  bioCsoft: http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.2/bioc
  cran: https://cran.rstudio.com
r_check_args: --install-args="--configure-args=\"--enable-build-minc\""
```

Any ideas on why this is failing? I can access the URL without issue in a browser and things are downloaded from https urls throughout the build process before this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer R versions have https support but that is an issue with building the current R built on the *ancient* Ubuntu version that Travis prescribes.

You could try to switch from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 by using

```
sudo: required

dist: trusty
```

which I do in a few setups (but I also use the first-generation Travis setup which I quite like, still).

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I didn't even realize I could request a trusty build worker for my testing, this changes everything.

Comment: Yes, Travis added this a while back and we maybe need to make this more widely know.  Thanks for accepting the answer, feel free to also upvote (click on 'up-triangle') if it helped.